# How do you get the options used to compile the currently running version of nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to recompile Nginx with some additional options, however I don't know what options the currently running package I am using already comes with. Is there any way to extract those options? ie. --with-http_ssl_module, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as that:

```
nginx -V
```

Output:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
built by gcc 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/ --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/ --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy/ --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/ --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi/ --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi/ --user=nginx --group=nginx --without-select_module --without-poll_module --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-perl=/usr/bin/perl --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-libatomic --with-compat --add-module=nginx_upstream_check_module-0.3.0 --add-dynamic-module=ngx-fancyindex-0.4.2 --add-dynamic-module=headers-more-nginx-module-0.33 --add-dynamic-module=nginx-rtmp-module-1.2.1 --with-cc-opt='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99 -fstack-protector' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -pie'
```